# Web Storm 9.0.3 typescript file watcher not work

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

I install typescript from `npm` and create typescript file watcher.
But web storm do not compile `ts` to `js` and show error in output tool window.

```
(cmd.exe /D /C "C:/Users/Muhammad Ali/AppData/Roaming/npm/tsc.cmd" --sourcemap "F:\M.Ali\Projects\Web Storm\Practice\js\file1.ts"
'C:/Users/Muhammad' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.)

Program path in filewatcher = C:\Users\Muhammad Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd
```

Comment: The error message seems to imply it doesn't like the space in your name as part of the path.  It's taking the part  before the space to be the command, and the part after the space as an argument.  Try removing the space from the path.

Answer (score 0):

> C:/Users/Muhammad Ali/AppData/Roaming/npm/tsc.cmd

This indicates you've done `npm install typescript -g`. Then you shouldn't need `cmd.exe`. Just run `tsc --sourcemap ......`

Comment: *"Just run tsc --sourcemap ......"* -- better name with extension -- `tsc.cmd` -- process spawning  will not add cmd/.exe/etc extensions automatically (only DOS/Console itself does it)